# Wrong proof of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Consider a ring $A=k[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$.
Our aim is to show that any maximal ideal is of the form $(x_1-x^0_1,\ldots, x_n-x_n^0)$ for some elements $x^0_i \in k$.

To do so, we prove the following fact by the induction on $n$: for any maximal ideal $m$, field $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/m$ is isomorphic to $k$.

Proof: case $n=1$, then $k[x_1]$ is PID, hence, $m=(f)$ for some $f=x_1^{k}+\ldots$.

It follows that $k[x]/m$ is finite over $k$, hence, is isomorphic to $k$
(because $k$ is algebraically closed).

Let us now suppose that the claim is true for $n-1$. Let us prove the induction step. Consider the ideal $\tilde{m}:=k[x_1,\ldots, x_{n-1}]\cap m$. It is a maximal ideal of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}]$, hence, by induction hypothesis we have $k[x_1,\ldots, x_{n-1}]/\tilde{m}=k$. It follows that $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/m=(k[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}]/\tilde{m})[x_n]/[m]=k[x_n]/[m]$. Now the desired follows from $n=1$ case.

The Hilbert's Nullstellensatz now directly follows.

The question is the following: this argument seems to be too short to be true (all the proofs I know are much longer), so what is wrong here?

Comment: Nice idea, but why is $\widetilde m $ a maximal ideal of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}]$?

Comment: Thank you! I get it. Here I exactly need finteness conditions.